# Network Printer on C# Windows Service Challenge

Tags: c#, .net, windows, web-services, wcf

I have a C# Windows Service on .Net Framework 4.5.2 as follows, and see a nice challenge. When I Run this program on Debug Mode, Network shared printer was found and all things work correctly but When I Change it to release Mode from VS then after that network shared printer was not found by my app. (tips: the following code store just last item, but this is brief piece of my code, when I get all printer in release mode on VS there is no one of shared printer list)

```
private static PrinterSettings GetPrinter(string printerName)
        {
            var printer = new PrinterSettings();
            foreach (string item in PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters)
            {
                printer.PrinterName = item;
              
        }
}
```

Where is the problem? How I can solve the issue?

Comment: Why do you think “network shared printer was not found”? You only store the name of the last printer in the list, and never expose that name.

Comment: @Corvus Noooo, This is just only a piece of an example of my code. please try to discover network shared printer, you will be surprised after that.

Comment: In general, the two models differ in the variables of some methods. The code you gave cannot be reproduced, I think there may be a problem calling System.Drawing.Printing. You may not need to bring variables in debug mode, but you need to add variables in release mode.